# Jasper report internationalization don't show cyrillic characters (russian for example)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, resourcebundle

i'am trying to generate multi language PDF using jasper report, i created properties file for different languages and i retrieve the labels using resource bundle , but the generated PDF don't display correctly russian characters
for the Jrxml file , i use the encoding UTF-8
this is my code to pass the bundle to the report:

```
  ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("labels/russia/labels", new Locale("ru", "RU"));

  paramMap.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", bundle);
  principalJsonDataSource = new JsonDataSource(inputAsStream);

  principalReport = JasperCompileManager
      .compileReport(context.getResource("classpath:jasper/russia/" + "russia" + ".jrxml").getInputStream());
  principalReport.setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataTypeEnum.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);
  principalReport.setProperty(MaxPagesGovernor.PROPERTY_MAX_PAGES_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE.toString());
  principalReport.setProperty(MaxPagesGovernor.PROPERTY_MAX_PAGES, String.valueOf(50));
  principalReport.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding", "UTF-8");

  principalReportPrinter = JasperFillManager.fillReport(principalReport, paramMap, principalJsonDataSource);
```

and this my jrxml file :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="justName" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="1170" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bf7f4e53-0f98-4a11-a8e2-91b1629156e5">
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
<property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit" value="pixel"/>
<import value="org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils"/>

<style name="Base" isDefault="true" fontSize="8" pdfFontName="Courier" pdfEncoding="UTF-8" isPdfEmbedded="false"/>

<queryString language="JSON">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>

<detail>
    <band height="201" splitType="Stretch">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
        <textField>
            <reportElement style="Base" positionType="Float" x="5" y="26" width="210" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="4e3fb833-2a8a-4178-89df-b0c229c6bc8f"/>


            <textElement>
                <font isBold="true"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{message}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a font that supports the needed characters, possibly embedding the font in the PDF.

You can try switching from `Courier` to `Courier New` font. As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/courier-new it supports Cyrillic characters.

Comment: thanks for response. I tried all kind of fonts but it does not work :(

Comment: @Amine are you embedding the font in the PDF?

Comment: yes actually i changed the property isPdfEmbedded to true but does not work

Comment: @Amine have you followed https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/adding-fonts-embedding-pdf ?

Comment: i used fonts extensions based on this [link](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html) and now the problem that even i packaged all files (.xml , jasperreport_extensions.properties, *ttf) to a .jar and put it in classpath , the report can't found the fonts

Comment: i used font extensions , and it work fine when i write characters directly **<textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Чайный"]]></textFieldExpression>** but it does not work when i use **<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{message}]]></textFieldExpression>** and retrieve the label from a properties file using resource bundle

Comment: @Amine How are you writing the UTF characters in properties? Properties file are usually encoded ASCII so you need to use `\uXXXX` notation.

Comment: like this **message=Чайный** . There is any solution to write directly the characters in my properties file without using \uXXXX ?

Comment: @Amine normally `*.properties` files are encoded as ASCII or windows-1252. Either encode your locale specific text as `\uXXXX` or don't use `*.properties`.

Comment: actually i took this [example](http://zetcode.com/articles/jasperresourcebundle/) and the author use *.properties and write directly russian characters